# SVG element pixelated on retina only if filters applied

Tags: svg, retina-display, svg-filters

An SVG path element becomes unexpectedly pixelated on retina screens if I apply a filter to it. Without the filter, it looks nice and smooth.

[image: An image showing two curves. The top one, labeled "without filters", is smooth. The bottom one, labeled "with filters", is noticeably pixelated]

I'm using a gaussian blur and a color matrix:

```xml
<filter id="svg-filter-rounded-corners" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" />
  <feColorMatrix mode="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 50 -25" />
</filter>
```

Here's a reproducible example. The circle on the left has the filter, the circle on the right does not.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" />
      <feColorMatrix mode="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 50 -25" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle filter="url(#filter)" cx="100" cy="100" r="90" fill="none" stroke="#221C35" stroke-width="10" />
  <circle cx="300" cy="100" r="90" fill="none" stroke="#221C35" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>
```

This is occurring in both Chrome and Firefox, on MacOS.

Is there anything I can do to keep the path smooth even with the filters applied?

Comment: Please post a complete working sample. That filter should be fine. Is this on Windows, Linux or Mac/iOS?  [ You might try reducing the values to something like 16 -8 -> high values sometimes cause browser issues ]

Comment: Hi @MichaelMullany — I've updated with a reproducible example. It's on MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is crispy even on Chrome/Windows. And the issue is that the values you're using for your feColorMatrix are too large. It's nuking the anti-aliasing completely. Try:

```
<feColorMatrix mode="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 -4" />
```

Which gives a more reasonable result. If you don't like that result, you could try a more detailed manipulation of opacity using feComponentTransfer instead of the feColorMatrix.

```
<feComponentTransfer>
 <feFuncA type="table" tableValues = "0 0 0 0 0.5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1"/>
</feComponentTransfer>
```

Comment: Proportionally stepping down the last two values of the `feColorMatrix` smoothed it out somewhat. Thanks for your help!